# Android 8.0: keeping a background service alive

Tags: android, background-service

I believe you all are already familiar with "background service limitations" imposed on Android 8.0 and up (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services).

I'm having a very particular problem right now. My application is meant for a very specific use case. App checks for certain data on the server every minute and in case of some wrong value, user is being alerted immediately. Obviously so far application was running in a form of background service and my customers never cared about (obvious) battery consumption coming from complex calculations that are being performed every minute.

Now, whole idea is that app needs to stay alive, working and in background (even with permanent notification, i don't have anything to hide) regardless of **anything**! If phone is in a deepest possible sleep state - service needs to keep running. If there's 2% battery left - service needs to keep running. So far, i managed to achieve that using alarms and "guardian services" which prevented any way of stopping the background service while app is installed. But now, with Android "0" - what's the way to go? Is there a JobScheduler that will guarantee execution at given rate (every minute) regardless of anything?

How SMS / Phone, WhatsApp and similar apps achieve that "awake no matter what" state?

Comment: I think you could benefit from an architecture revision. How about you use an AWS Lambda running off an event rule triggered every minute to monitor the state of your server. Then if something is wrong you can trigger an event that gets sent to the user's device through conventional push notifications.

Comment: I spent almost two weeks and managed to make it work. you have to write a background service extending Service class. then you have to make notification and show it as foreground, only then Android O will not kill your service. Leme know if you require detailed answer if this is not enough.

Comment: Faisal something like "sticky" background service? What about "Doze" mode? user3474985: unfortunately i can't edit the server-side app as it's managed by other company and offers the same API for a lot of non-android services. I'm in the "fix it, we don't care" situation where my app worked for years, and now on some new devices it won't work reliably anymore.

Comment: yes exactly! implement that, there is no other for Android O. Or no other way as far as I know cz I spent so much time on this.

Comment: I just read documentation of Doze mode. So, you are concerned that if your service terminated by Doze mode? if you return sticky from service, it restarts it self if system terminates it so nothing to worry. BTW, I tested my service while running it 2/3 weeks and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's what Google tells us.

> A process is not forever.
>   If you feel you need your foreground service to stay alive
>   permanently, then this is an indicator that a foreground service is
>   not the right answer.

[Effective foreground services on Android](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/effective-foreground-services-on-android_11.html)

I think you could use repetitive tasks with WorkManager or change the architecture and use FCM. In any case, Google will not let us work as it did before.